# Why is React telling me that this.handleClick is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple calculator with React, and I am trying to add an onClick function to a button. I am using the same technique used in the react tutorial with the tictactoe game, but when I click any button, I just get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.handleClick is not a function
    at onClick (index.js:71)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:306)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:389)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:414)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:3278)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3287)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:3259)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3304)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3514)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3558)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21871)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:795)
    at dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:3568)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4267)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4189)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21887)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:806)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:4168)
```

My code is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class Screen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>99+10</p>
    );
  }
}

class Operators extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.renderButton('+')}
        {this.props.renderButton('-')}
        {this.props.renderButton('x')}
        {this.props.renderButton('/')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Numbers extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="nums-row">
          {this.props.renderButton(1)}
          {this.props.renderButton(2)}
          {this.props.renderButton(3)}
        </div>
        <div className="nums-row">
          {this.props.renderButton(4)}
          {this.props.renderButton(5)}
          {this.props.renderButton(6)}
        </div>
        <div className="nums-row">
          {this.props.renderButton(7)}
          {this.props.renderButton(8)}
          {this.props.renderButton(9)}
        </div>
        <div className="nums-row">
          {this.props.renderButton('.')}
          {this.props.renderButton(0)}
          {this.props.renderButton('=')}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function CalculatorButton(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick} >
      {props.text}
    </button>
  );
}

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  handleClick(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }

  renderButton(text) {
    return (
      <CalculatorButton 
        onClick= {() => this.handleClick(text)}
        text={text}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="calculator-container">
        <div className="calculator">
          <div className="screen">
            <Screen /> 
          </div>
          <div className="buttons">
            <div className="numbers">
              <Numbers renderButton={this.renderButton} />
            </div>
            <div className="operators">
              <Operators renderButton={this.renderButton} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calculator />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is a picture of the interface, so that it may be easier to understand what I said in the beginning of the question.

[image: app UI]

Thank you for the help, in advance.

Comment: Because you want `evt => this.handleClick(evt)` (or ridiculous `.bind()` calls in your constructor). There has not been magical `this` rebinding since React 15, so you're back to the reality of JS: when an event fires, it fires in global scope, not "your object"s scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the `renderButton` function to the `Calculator` component instance.

This can be done in several ways:

**#1.** in the constructor:

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderButton = this.renderButton.bind(this);
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

**#2.** in the render:

```
<Numbers renderButton={this.renderButton.bind(this)} />
```

**#3.** or by changing the `renderButton` method to an arrow function:

```
renderButton = (text) => {
  /* ... */
}
```

More details along with some pros and cons can be found in the [React faq section on functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance).

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.renderButton('+')` calls `renderButton` **immediately** and assigns the **return value** as the event handler.

This is [specifically covered in the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> ```
> <button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
> <button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
> ```
>
> The above two lines are equivalent, and use arrow functions and
>   Function.prototype.bind respectively.
>
> In both cases, the e argument representing the React event will be
>   passed as a second argument after the ID. With an arrow function, we
>   have to pass it explicitly, but with bind any further arguments are
>   automatically forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

To Solve your issue, just use Arrow function. To do so, please **replace** two event handler **handleClick and renderButton** with the following code. It works perfectly.

```
handleClick = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
};

renderButton = (text) => {
    return (
        <CalculatorButton
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(text)}
            text={text}
        />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the onclick to null, think is correct to me for
<ComboSelect ... onClick={null} />

Answer (score 0):

My error was because of my import path was wrong after I rewrite it it works. maybe this can help.